# ASP.NET MVC4 - display HTML containing string as raw HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a string, read from a database, that contains HTML that I want to output. Despite applying `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`, the View always renders the string as encoded HTML (i.e. `&lt;SPAN&gt;` instead of `<SPAN>`).

I am using:

```
string test = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(myStr);
<span>@test</span>
```

I have tried:

```
string test = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStr);
<span>@test</span>

<span>@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStr)</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@Html.Raw("<span>Hello</span>")
```

All the output from helpers and other elements in Razor are put through `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, unless they implement `IHtmlString`. But your best option here is using `Html.Raw()`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `@Html.Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw("<h1>Header</h1>")
```

Will output the text `Header`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this helper method

```
@Html.Raw(myStr)
```